# Include css in struts2 jsp page

Tags: java, css, jsp, struts2, struts

My struts2 project structure as follows

```
Webcontent
  css
    abc.css
  jsp
    login.jsp
  META-INF
  WEB-INF
```

indeed to include the functions of abc.css in login page.How can i do that ? How can i give the path of css file in jsp page ?

Comment: The same way you give the path to *any* file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your css with the following statement.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/abc.css">
</head>
```

"../css/abc.css" is a relative path.

"../" represents one directory up. i.e., Login.jsp is in "jsp" directory "../" will make the directory as "Webcontent"

"../css" will traverse you upto "css" directory in the "Webcontent".

"../css/abc.css" will give the abc.css file.

Comment: one more help.I have another folder 'images' and it contain some images. How can i specify the path of image in css file. is this correct ?  background:url(../images/1.jpg)

Comment: Note that the relative path to the css file is relative to the URL of the page (e.g. as seen by a user's browser). If you are using Struts then the URL to the page will not be /mystrutsapp/jsp/login.jsp, it is more likely to be something like /mystrutsapp/login.action. So using ../css/abc.css will work but not for the reason given in this answer. For example, if you move login.jsp into a subdirectory such as jsp/login/login.jsp then "../css/abc.css" would still work (../../css/abc.css wouldn't)

Comment: Using relative paths for things like CSS etc is almost always a bad idea. Use absolute paths for static resources.

Answer (score 0):

you can include  your css file like this.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Webcontent/css/abc.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Do you know what /Webcontent is?